# Is the inline image or the referenced on better In html emails?

Tags: html, email, html-email

I would like to know some pros and cons about the which solution is better in html email when we are  dealing with images.

If the image is attached inline?
Or if it is referenced and stored in a public url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loading of images referenced from a public URI will often be blocked by the Mail User Agent (Thunderbird e.g.) to protect the user's privacy and avoid tracking.

So attaching them is the best way to have the images shown to the receipient.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the better way is url img :

- lighter
- attaching picture can be blocked by antivirus/spyware
- some users disable images because they have enough speed or not to waste their package. Remember that mobile is increasingly used!
- When a Mail User Agent protect the user privacy, you need respect
  that. You needed to interest your client with your title, your text
  content so that it unlocks pictures.

I send mass mailling every week. I do not consider myself pro.
You can To analyze several newsletters. You'll see what the professionals do.

PS : sorry for my bad english =)